# How to mock getClient?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a function :

```
func HTTPGet(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    resp, err := getClient().Get(url)
    return resp, err
}
```

and getClient function is :

```
var defaultClient *http.Client
func getClient() *http.Client {
    if defaultClient == nil {
        defaultClient = &http.Client{
            Timeout:   time.Second * 60,
            Transport: newDefaultTransport(),
        }
    }
    return defaultClient
}
```

I need to write testcase for HTTPGet for url : "/catalog/v6/providers".

I have written testcase for default URL like :

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, Client")
}
func TestHTTPGet(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(Handler))
    defer ts.Close()
    mockServerURL := ts.URL
    resp, err := HTTPGet(mockServerURL)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    assertEquals("Hello, Client", fmt.Sprintf("%s", body), t)
}
```

But How to write testcase for specific URL.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What have you tried? What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I think the OP wants to test that the func HTTPGet sends a request with the passed in url.

Comment: `getClient` seems to be irrelevant to this question. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read and save the requested url in the following manner:

```
var receivedURL string
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    receivedURL = r.RequestURI
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, Client")
}
```

Then later just assert it:

```
func TestHTTPGet(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(Handler))
    defer ts.Close()
    mockServerURL := ts.URL
    url := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", mockServerURL, '/path/to/test')
    resp, err := HTTPGet(mockServerURL)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    assertEquals(receivedURL, url, t)
}
```